# Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation error when trying to delete a file form server

Tags: asp.net

I am in asp.net, C#, .net FrameWork 4.0
I have a file in my downloads folder in my webhost that i can't delete it now! i can delete any other files, but just this one and one or two more files has such this problem.

I don't know the reason... but i think there is a problem in the file security.
When i attemp to delete the file with this way:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("file.dat");
if (fi.Exists) fi.Delete();
```

The file name and the path is correct and available in the path.
so fi.Exists returns true then fi.Delete executes...
but raises this error "Access to the path ... is denied!"

I thought that the permission for my app is limited and can not delete the file.
So i decided to set a FullControl permission to the file like this:

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo("file.dat");
FileSecurity sec = fi.GetAccessControl();
sec.AddAccessRule(new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
fi.SetAccessControl(sec);
```

but now, raises this error: **Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation**

Where is the problem...???
How can i allow my app to delete all files without problem...???
Pleas help me sooner...
Thanx...

Comment: It seems your application doesn't have the necessary right to change the security permission of files, you can't do anything form your code, I'd suggest check the app permission in IIS or contact support.

Comment: How can i check app permissions in my locale IIS?

Comment: Note, same happens if you try to add a `CryptoKeyAccessRule`, too.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to change the permissions to the file prior to running any code to make sure IIS Usr or all users have access.  Remember your ASP.NET application is running under the context of the application pool.  The only way to run under another context is to turn on impersonation.  This could be a case that the file was created on a different server (load balancing) under a local account that runs IIS and now it can't remove it because the permissions are different.  If you run under a specific context in your application pool (service account etc.) then you should not have these issues.

More information on impersonation is at this link (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5(v=vs.100).aspx).

When using impersonation, ASP.NET applications can execute with the Windows identity (user account) of the user making the request. Impersonation is commonly used in applications that rely on Microsoft Internet Information Services (IIS) to authenticate the user.
ASP.NET impersonation is disabled by default. If impersonation is enabled for an ASP.NET application, that application runs in the context of the identity whose access token IIS passes to ASP.NET. That token can be either an authenticated user token, such as a token for a logged-in Windows user, or the token that IIS provides for anonymous users (typically, the IUSR_MACHINENAME identity).
When impersonation is enabled, only your application code runs under the context of the impersonated user. Applications are compiled and configuration information is loaded using the identity of the ASP.NET process. For more information, see Configuring ASP.NET Process Identity. The compiled application is put in the Temporary ASP.NET files directory. The application identity that is being impersonated needs to have read/write access to this directory. The impersonated application identity also requires at least read access to the files in your application directory and subdirectories. For more information, see ASP.NET Required Access Control Lists (ACLs).

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: How can i set these settings that you are mean...? I mean in my locale IIS i have setted the site aplication pool to .Net4.5 ! now what do i must do to get my problem solved...? is there some settings in my IIS that i must set theme??

Comment: Where is your file share that you are trying to access?  I included more information about impersonation above.

Comment: The account your site is using is found in the Application Pool's advanced settings, of the app pool your site is using.  It is the "Identity" property.  If you don't want to use the built-in account, you'd have to specify an account and give it the privileges to do your operation, or if the user of your site will have these privileges, you'd have to add that block above to your web.config and enable ASP.NET Impersonation, found in Your Web Site > IIS section > Authentication. Select it, then select Enable.